# Ghoscript: PDF/A or PDF/X → regular PDF?

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, ghostscript, pdfa

How can I use `gs` to convert a PDF/A or PDF/X file to a regular PDF file?

Comment: Any PDF/A or PDF/X is a valid PDF file per definition. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: As it has been said, any PDF/A or PDF/X (or PDF/E or PDF/UA etc.) document is a valid PDF. The primary key to recognize a PDF as a PDF/A or PDF/X or... is a specific value in the metadata. That means, all you would have to do to strip the document from the "special" variant of PDF is to delete that particular metadata entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Ghostscript to 'convert' a PDF file, only to take a PDF as an input, and produce a new PDF as an output. If you simply pass the PDF as an input to Ghostscript, and use the pdfwrite device then it will produce an equivalent PDF for you, unless you specify PDF/A or PDF/X it won't be produced to either standard.

In any event, why would you want to do this ? A PDF/A or PDF/X file is  simply a valid PDF file which adheres to certain additional restrictions.

Comment: I have some PDF/A files of scanned e-books that load really slowly. They appear to use a DjVu-like multi-layer compression. Is this not something specific to PDF/A? For such PDFs, using "Ghostscript to 'convert' a PDF file, … [taking] a PDF as an input, and produce a new PDF as an output," causes GS to choke.

Comment: @Geremia Any PDF/A or PDF/X document is also a PDF document. What you want is some conversion of PDF file containing certain constructions (you do not want) to other PDFs not containing them.

Comment: Geremia, not that's not a feature of PDF/A, its is presumably the way the PDF file has been constructed (ie badly). What do you mean by 'choke' ? If you have a file which won't process through a reasonably recent version of Ghostscript then please raise a bug report. However, given that the file apparently renders slowly to a screen resolution the likelihood is that its just really slow.

Comment: @KenS: You're probably right; I think it's just a super-compressed PDF.

Comment: If it's a compression thing, you're probably looking either at JPEG-2000 compression or JBIG2 compression (the former for color images, the latter for black-and-white images). These images do indeed display extremely slowly on for example older tablet devices, because they require more processing power to uncompress. Changing compression to JPEG and CCITT compression for example might help (though it might decrease quality of the image or (potentially vastly) increase file size).

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same answer , as if you want to print your pdf file, printers only except pdf/x format. this is the gs script i have been using;

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=new.pdf original.pdf
```